# Derivative continuous at a point implies derivative exists in a neighborhood?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c)$ exists and $f'$ is continuous at $c$.

Does this mean that $f'$ exists for a neighborhood $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$?

My attempt:

I think the answer should be yes, because $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=f'(c)$ implies that there exists $\delta$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta$, then $|f'(x)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the statement "$f^{\prime}$ is continuous at $c$" already assume that $f^{\prime}$ exists in a neighborhood of $c$? If not, how are you defining continuity?

Comment: To say ``$f'$ is continuous at $c$'', you actually presumed that $f'$ has been defined in a neighborhood of $c$, so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: No. Consider any function $f:\mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at only a single point $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The derivative is continuous there since $f'$ is defined only at an isolated point.